# DESCRIPTION' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114048/column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-ag)

I am  a newbie in SQL querying; I'm getting this error:

> "DESCRIPTION' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

I can't find the right aggregate function. I need something like `unique(DESCRIPTION)` in my select statement

My description column is unique varchar values, any idea?

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID,INDEX,STATUS,DESCRIPTION,TS)
SELECT ID,min(INDEX),STATUS,DESCRIPTION,min(TS) from myTable2 t1top
WHERE (EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Completed' )) 
GROUP BY ID, STATUS
ORDER BY ID  DESC, STATUS DESC
```

Comment: You did not provide your query that was throwing this error. Please do that.

Comment: If you have two different description values for a given id and status, which one do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add DESCRIPTION to your GROUP BY list, it should work

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID,INDEX,STATUS,DESCRIPTION,TS)
SELECT ID,min(INDEX),STATUS,DESCRIPTION,min(TS) from myTable2 t1top
WHERE (EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Completed' )) 
GROUP BY ID, STATUS, DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY ID  DESC, STATUS DESC
```

but that doesn't mean your query is correct - depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SELECT DISTINCT description**.  Or something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ID,INDEX,STATUS,DESCRIPTION,TS)
SELECT ID, min(INDEX), STATUS, DESCRIPTION, min(TS) 
    FROM myTable2 t1top
WHERE (EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE ID=t1top.ID AND STATUS='Completed' )) 
GROUP BY ID, STATUS, DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY ID  DESC, STATUS DESC
```

The key point to remember is that every field you select in an aggregate query needs to be either inside an aggregate function like *SUM*, *MAX*, etc, **or** contained in the group-by clause.  This is different to MySql, which does not enforce that rule for queries, but simply returns unpredictable results.

Comment: would you please kinda mondify the query above, I dont fully Underestand

Comment: @user1429595 updated.  The error message means you need to add *Description* to the *Group by* clause, or make it an aggregate.